# I want show modal in the index view

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to show the modal on Index page while I do not want it to open in another view that It is in it I use this code but it has error

```
<div id="mymodal"  class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">&times;</button>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div id="bodyModal" class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section mysection
{
    <script>
          
        function myinsert() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/InsertPermission/",
                type: "Get",
                data: {}
            }).done(function (result) {
                $('#mymodal').modal('show');
                $('#bodyModal').html(result);
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Could you show the error pls?

Comment: it does not show an error, but my problem is that the modal is not shown in this view. I used ajax to show it. Is there another way?

Comment: it does not show an error, but my problem is that the medal is not shown in this view. I used ajax to show it. Is there another way?

Comment: Did you try to put  $('#bodyModal').html(result); at fist and after this  $('#mymodal').modal('show'); ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not solved

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not solved

Comment: instead of $('#bodyModal').html(result); try $('#mymodal  .modal-body').html(result);

Comment: and change " url: "/Admin/InsertPermission/" to " url: "/Admin/InsertPermission"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead of  $('#bodyModal').html(result):

```
 $('#mymodal .modal-body').html(result); 
$('#mymodal').modal('show');
```

and change url: "/Admin/InsertPermission/" to

```
url: "/Admin/InsertPermission"
```